# python scoping and run order in building namespace

Tags: python

Why does this not work in python?, where I can access the enclosing scope (here global scope) when there are no other references to the same variable but can't when there are.

Does the interpreter look further down the function first before for the variable definition, finds it so assumes it is only a local variable which hasn't yet been assigned a value?  What's the run order of the interpreter here?

```
> a = 5
> a
Out[3]: 
5
> def closure():
    print(a)

> closure()
5
> def closure():
    print(a)
    a = "another"
    return a
> closure()

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `global a` to the first line of the function.